Trying to access the panic info message causes a mismatched types error?
When trying to compile this bootkit project, I get an error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> bootkit\src/main.rs:33:16
   |
33 | if let Some(message) = info.message() {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -------------- this expression has type `PanicMessage<'_>`
   | |
   | expected `PanicMessage<'_>`, found `Option<_>`.
   |
   = note: expected struct `PanicMessage<'_>`
                found enum `Option<_>`

This is the part of the code where the error occurs:
#[panic_handler]
fn panic_handler(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    if let Some(location) = info.location() {
        log::error!(
            "[-] Panic in {} at ({}, {}):",
            location.file(),
            location.line(),
            location.column()
        );
        if let Some(message) = info.message() {
            log::error!("[-] {}", message);
        }
    }

    loop {}
}


What version of the compiler are you compiling with?

last version cargo and nightly @cafce25

Please [edit] that information into your post, also please specify which version exactly as "last version" does change quite a lot especially for nightly and such will be useless next month/a year from now/…

While it used to return an Option, recent PanicInfo::message since #115974 no longer is fallible and returns a plain PanicMessage, just remove the if let.
#[panic_handler]
fn panic_handler(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    if let Some(location) = info.location() {
        log::error!(
            "[-] Panic in {} at ({}, {}):",
            location.file(),
            location.line(),
            location.column()
        );
        let message = info.message();
        log::error!("[-] {message}");
    }

    loop {}
}

It's not uncommon for unstable functions to change their signature, always make sure you check against your compilers version of the documentation to avoid such confusions.
